# Working {full throttle} on her paper?

Tags: usage

I just joined StackExchange and here's my first grammar question:

Is my use of **full throttle** in the following sentence correct?

> She has a paper due tomorrow and is working "**full throttle**" on it.

Comment: Yes, you are using that idiom correctly. The preposition "at" is sometimes added to the front, i.e. "at full throttle", but it is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

> She has a paper due tomorrow and is working "full throttle" on it

There is nothing grammatically wrong, but it might be better to write

> She has a paper due tomorrow and is working full-throttle on it

or

> She has a paper due tomorrow and is working at full throttle on it

Using "full-throttle" as an adverb (which is what you are doing here) is a little sketchy, and I think the hyphen improves it.

Using the preposition phrase "at full throttle" makes the thing perfectly clear.

I don't think the quotation marks added anything of value.

Comment: Thanks.I used the quotation marks to put emphasis on the part of the sentence I was referring to..

Comment: I don't think the hyphen is needed here. Here is an example of **full throttle** that I found on Google books, and which is exactly the way I used it: _"The men were working **full throttle** to get the corn and beans harvested."_

Comment: That hyphen looks awkward to me. Expressions like _full throttle_ and _full speed_ are common enough that I think it's best to omit the hyphen. @GrammarBoy - You probably shouldn't use quotation marks for "emphasis." They look like [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes), and I would interpret that to mean that they were being lazy, and not truly working with a full effort.